# Rendering react table using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I am using react table to render data using an API call. To give an overview, when the user clicks on a link, based on the navigation location path, the URL of the API, and the columns of the react table are all set and used to fetch data from the API. The data from the API is used to render the table. I am getting an error saying Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

Here is my code

SharedTable2.jsx

```
const SharedTable2 = ({
  sortDirections,
  setSortDirections,
  toggleDetail,
  setToggleDetail,
}) => {
const [dataApi, setDataApi] = useState([]);
  console.log(dataApi);
  const [prevData, setPrevData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    let formData1 = formDatas[getLastPathName(location.pathname)];
    setFormData(formDatas[getLastPathName(location.pathname)]);
    const fetchData = (url, formData) => {
      axios
        .post(url, formData)
        .then((response) => {
          // Update the state with the fetched data
          const newData = response.data;

          if (newData !== prevData) {
            setDataApi(newData);
            setPrevData(newData);
          }
          setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          setError(true);
        });
    };
    fetchData(url, formData1);
  }, [location.pathname]);
 if (
    isLoading ||
    dataApi === null ||
    dataApi === undefined ||
    dataApi.length === 0
  ) {
    return <div>Loading.......</div>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error while fetching data</div>;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <SharedTable3
        COLUMNS={column}
        DATA={dataApi}
        setFormData={setFormData}
        sortDirections={sortDirections}
        setSortDirections={setSortDirections}
        toggleDetail={toggleDetail}
        setToggleDetail={setToggleDetail}
      </>
);
};
export default SharedTable2;
```

SharedTable3.jsx

```
const SharedTable3 = ({
  COLUMNS,
  DATA,
  setFormData,
  sortDirections,
  setSortDirections,
  toggleDetail,
  setToggleDetail,
}) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  // Setting State for selected Row
  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState({});

  // Get row value on row onClick
  const getRowValue = (e) => {
    setToggleDetail(true);
    setSelectedRow(e.original);
  };

  const tableData = (data) => {
    switch (getLastPathName(location.pathname)) {
      case "status":
        return data.statusMessages;
        break;
      case "activexml":
        return data.statusMessages;
        break;
      case "catalogues":
        return data.catalogueInformation;
        break;
      default:
        return data.statusMessages;
    }
  };

  const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, []);
  const data = tableData(DATA);

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    page,
    prepareRow,
    setPageSize,
    state: { pageSize },
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      initialState: { pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 25 },
    },

    usePagination
  );
 return (
    <>
      <div
        className="d-flex flex-fill"
        style={{ height: "60%", overflowY: "auto" }}
      >
        <div className="flex-fill m-2 " style={{ overflowY: "auto" }}>
          <table
            {...getTableProps()}
            className=" table"
            style={{ overflowX: "auto" }}
          >
            <thead
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0",
                background: "white",
              }}
            >
              {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                <tr
                  className="border border-2"
                  {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}
                >
                  {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                    <th
                      {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                      style={{
                        position: "sticky",
                        top: "0",
                      }}
                    >
                      {column.disableClick ? (
                        <span className="d-flex">
                          {column.render("Header")}
                        </span>
                      ) : (
                        <span
                          onClick={() => handleHeaderClick(column.id)}
                          className="d-flex"
                          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        >
                          {column.render("Header")}
                          <span className="ms-auto">
                            {sortDirections[column.id] &&
                              (sortDirections[column.id]
                                ? sortDirections[column.id] === "DESC"
                                  ? "▲"
                                  : "▼"
                                : null)}
                          </span>
                        </span>
                      )}
                    </th>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              ))}
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
              {page.length > 0 ? (
                page.map((row) => {
                  prepareRow(row);
                  return (
                    <tr
                      {...row.getRowProps()}
                      onClick={() => getRowValue(row)}
                      style={{
                        background:
                          selectedRow === row.original && toggleDetail
                            ? "#edf1f6"
                            : "",
                        // cursor: "pointer",
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                        <td
                          className="p-1"
                          style={{
                            cursor: "pointer",
                            verticalAlign: "middle",
                          }}
                          {...cell.getCellProps()}
                        >
                          {cell.render("Cell")}
                        </td>
                      ))}
                    </tr>
                  );
                })
              ) : (
                <tr>
                  <td colSpan={columns.length} className="text-center">
                    No data to show
                  </td>
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          {/* <div className="bg-white p-1"></div> */}
        </div>

        {getLastPathName(location.pathname) === "status" ? (
          <>
            {/*Vertical Divider */}
            <div
              className="bg-dark col-1 mx-2"
              style={{
                width: "2px",
                display: toggleDetail ? "block" : "none",
              }}
            ></div>
            {/* Side Detail */}
            <SharedSideDetail
              toggleDetail={toggleDetail}
              setToggleDetail={setToggleDetail}
              selectedRow={selectedRow}
              setSelectedRow={setSelectedRow}
              setShowPopUpError={setShowPopUpError}
            />
          </>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SharedTable3;
```

I have observed that even when data changes, the sharedtable3 is not re-rendered. The `useTable` is somehow still using old data. Please Help!

Comment: where is the forEach in the code?

Comment: I think foreach is internal to the usetable, when it's trying to loop through the columns or data

Comment: can you share value of dataApi after api call??

Comment: Hi, can you provide a working code in codesandbox with some sample data? 
It will definitely help others to provide you with the answer. Thanks

Comment: Hey the error statement's got to reveal more info. Can share more of it? As in, the file, line, character etc.? It's quite possible that we're looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `formDatas` in the dependency array of `useEffect` because inside it you use its value to create `formData1`.
if over time `formDatas` gets updates, `useEffect` will not track that, so it may return unexpected data to `formData1`, which may lead to the error.
 the problem with that is `useEffect` will fire each time `formDatas` is updated so you have to handle this.

---

another solution is to create a ref `formDatasRef` and update it each time `formDatas` is updated:

```js
const formDatasRef = useRef();
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
 formDatasRef.current = formDatas;
},[formDatas])
```

and use it instead of `formDatas` to create `formData1`.
 this way you ensure that you have always to updated value of `formDatas` in `formDatasRef.current`:

```
useEffect(() => {
if(formDatasRef.current){ // you may don't need to run the code inside useEffect when formDatasRef is not set i.e component first mount
  setIsLoading(true);
  let formData1 = formDatasRef.current[getLastPathName(location.pathname)];
  setFormData(formDatasRef.current[getLastPathName(location.pathname)]);
  const fetchData = (url, formData) => {
    //...
  };
  fetchData(url, formData1);
}
},[location.pathname]);
```

**Note** that `useEffect` will run when the component first mounts

Answer (score 0):

When the component `SharedTable3` is mounted the `DATA={dataApi}` is undefined, that is the reason you get "*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')*".

To avoid this issue you should use:

```js
const data = tableData(DATA ? DATA : [ ] );
```

in `SharedTable3.jsx`